# Error when run pod install after add swiftLint to project

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swiftlint

**Long story short**

I'm trying to add SwiftLint into my project using cocoapods, but after I add the run script, I'm unable to perform `pod install` and `pod update` without error.

Every time that I execute `pod install` I get the error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.2/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:67:in `url_for_request': uninitialized constant GhInspector::Sidekick::ERB (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.2/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:24:in `search'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.2/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:65:in `search_query'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.2/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:59:in `search_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in `search_for_exceptions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:67:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

**Full description now**

Start from the beginning of the process to use SwiftLint, I'm add it to my podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'Realm'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'SwiftLint'

end
```

Then I install my pods without any error.

After this I add the `.swiftlint.yml` file with:

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
 - trailing_whitespace

excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
 - Pods
```

At this point I'm still able to execute `pod install` and `pod update` like a charm, but SwiftLint configuration still miss one last step to work.

After I add the run script

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
    swiftlint
else
    echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

SwiftLint start to work, but, as I said at the beginning of the question, I'm unable to run `pod install` and `pod update`

**Versions data**

ruby version:
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]

cocoapods version:
1.5.3

SwiftLint version:
0.27.0

Any idea of how can I solve this error?

Comment: You are probably installing the latest version which needs a higher ruby version that you have. Can you provide your version for ruby, cocoapods, swiftlint

Comment: I added the versions on the question, I will check the compatibility right now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment seems ok.
Did you create another run script?
Put the swiftlint script on run script that already exists, or give a different name for every "Run Script" you create.

Comment: You were right, I added the run script to the same run script of Fabric and the `pod install` started to work again! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"`

Updated your run script to this